# environment variable for current directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set an environment variable to reflect the a folder in current workspace that is needed by my make system.

In settings.json I have

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "MY_SPECIAL_DIR": "${workspaceRoot}/special"
}
```

but it is just evaluated as "/special" during the build.  What is the scoping of the built-in variables like workspaceRoot?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) VS Code reference, the variable you are looking for is `${workspaceFolder}`.
Therefore your snippet should be changed to the following:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "MY_SPECIAL_DIR": "${workspaceFolder}/special"
}
```

Furthermore, you can replace the `/` character with the variable `${pathSeparator}` in case you want your settings file to be compatible across filesystems that use distinct characters as path separators.

As of the variables' scope, there is a [section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_variables-scoped-per-workspace-folder) on the aforementioned reference about it. Basically: all variables are available at the outermost scope, and you can resolve the ambiguity of multiple folders in the workspace by mentioning its basename.